# Convert sub-query with "NOT IN" operator to join with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I need to convert the following sub-query to JOIN. Here I already have JOIN operator in the inner query. Please help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Consultants 
WHERE  Consultants.ConsIntID 
NOT IN  (SELECT Links.ToID 
         FROM   Links JOIN Reminders 
         ON Links.FromID = Reminders.RemIntID 
            AND ApptSubType = 'Placed' 
            AND ToID LIKE 'CS%')
```

Comment: Why Do you need to do that?

Comment: Try typing SQL join subquery into a search engine (apparently lmgtfy is not an allowed link address)

Comment: For one, please re-write the `Links, Reminders` join using [proper, modern JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), and also [you should be referencing the schema every time](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). But I agree with JohnFx - why do you want to replace this with a join? If anything, [I would change it to a NOT EXISTS](https://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: @user3056839 [that is not allowed because those that control have decided that it's pretty rude](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=lmgtfy).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yet somehow justified in this situation...

Comment: I would use where not exists too

Comment: @user3056839 I'm not saying I agree, just telling you why it's not allowed.

Comment: I don't see an `outer-join`. Please remove the tag.

Comment: @JohnFx The application I work on has a limitation. If I use sub-queries, the search option in my application would not work properly. So I need the query using joins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright so you probably shouldn't change this to a join I would use `NOT EXISTS` the reasons for doing so are stated [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

I've also replace your ancient join syntax and added aliases to clear this up. The method shown below has been the accepted standard for about 22 years now and is the [preferred](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) way to write queries.

```sql
SELECT C.* 
FROM   Consultants  as C -- aliases are very useful for clarity
WHERE  
NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
         FROM   Links as L 
         INNER JOIN Reminders  as R --New join syntax
            ON  L.FromID = R.RemIntID 
         WHERE C.ConsIntID = L.ToID 
         AND ApptSubType = 'Placed' 
         AND ToID LIKE 'CS%'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Consultants 
WHERE  Consultants.ConsIntID 
NOT IN  (SELECT Links.ToID 
         FROM   Links 
         JOIN   Reminders  ON(Links.FromID = Reminders.RemIntID)
         WHERE  ApptSubType = 'Placed' 
                AND ToID LIKE 'CS%')
```